# Whats wrong with my wp gallery?

Tags: media, gallery, uploads

i was making a gallery on my clients site using `[gallery]` sortcode. The gallery appears but when clicked it goes to clients other website which i have no idea why?

here is the link http://www.build12.com/promotions-pictures/pictures/ check the wired link of the pictures.

The wordpress version is 3.1.1. Please let me know what is your advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at your javascript in the header for the thumb info:

```
script>
var thumbfile = "http://bricksandwindows.build12.com";
```

also repeated on line 179 when viewing source

Comment: Thanks! It might some junk code from earlier developer. I will check and let you know tomorrow. It is late here :)